# download image form server then share to instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I'm trying to share an image after i download it from the server to instagram, this is the code i`m using to download the image form the server

```
- (IBAction) DownloadImage:(id)sender {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sender];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImage *viewImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(img));

        });
    });
}
```

now the image is saved to photo album, how can open it in instagram app directly after it have been downloaded ?

image size is always more than 612x612px

Answer (score 0):

After a while i found the answer and modified it to my code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;


- (IBAction) DownloadImage:(id)sender {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sender];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImage *screenShot = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

            NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
            [UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

            _dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
            _dic.delegate = self;
            _dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";

            NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
                [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
            }

            else {
                NSLog(@"no instagram app found");
            }
        });
    });
}
```